How to get a `1 to 1` correlation data frame from a long data frame in R
I have a long data frame as follows:
a <- data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                name=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
                value=c(0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1)
                )
## > a
##   group name value
## 1     1    A   0.2
## 2     1    B   0.3
## 3     1    C   1.0
## 4     2    A   0.3
## 5     2    B   0.6
## 6     2    C   0.1
##

I want get the pair correlations in the name column, thus I need to get a data frame as follows:
out1 <- data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  name1=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
                  value1=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 1, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                  name2=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
                  value2=c(0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1)
                  )

## > out1
##    group name1 value1 name2 value2
## 1      1     A    0.2     A    0.2
## 2      1     A    0.2     B    0.3
## 3      1     A    0.2     C    1.0
## 4      1     B    0.3     A    0.2
## 5      1     B    0.3     B    0.3
## 6      1     B    0.3     C    1.0
## 7      1     C    1.0     A    0.2
## 8      1     C    1.0     B    0.3
## 9      1     C    1.0     C    1.0
## 10     2     A    0.3     A    0.3
## 11     2     A    0.3     B    0.6
## 12     2     A    0.3     C    0.1
## 13     2     B    0.6     A    0.3
## 14     2     B    0.6     B    0.6
## 15     2     B    0.6     C    0.1
## 16     2     C    0.1     A    0.3
## 17     2     C    0.1     B    0.6
## 18     2     C    0.1     C    0.1
##

Or remove the overlapping:
out2 <- data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                   name1=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
                   value1=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6),
                   name2=c('B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
                   value2=c(0.3, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1)
                   )
## > out2
##   group name1 value1 name2 value2
## 1     1     A    0.2     B    0.3
## 2     1     A    0.2     C    1.0
## 3     1     B    0.3     C    1.0
## 4     2     A    0.3     B    0.6
## 5     2     A    0.3     C    0.1
## 6     2     B    0.6     C    0.1
##

Finally, I get the correlation plot as follows:
ppa <- ggplot(data=out2, aes(x=value1, y=value2, color=name1))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method='lm',level=0.99)+
    facet_grid(name2~name1)
ggsave(ppa, file='t1.png', width=5, height=4)


Is there an elegant way to achieve my purpose? (I prefer dplyr, but base R is also OK).
Also, how to get an upper or lower triangle？
Thanks for your help.

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  name = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
  value = c(0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1)
) |>
  nest(combos = c(name, value)) |>
  mutate(combos = lapply(combos, function(d) {
    t(apply(t(combn(3, 2)), 1, FUN = function(r) { unlist(d[r, ]) })) |>
      as_tibble() |>
      mutate(across(starts_with("value"), as.numeric))
  })) |>
  unnest(combos) |>
  ggplot(aes(value1, value2, color = name1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x) +
  facet_grid(name2 ~ name1)


Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0

What about using cross_join()?
cross_join(a, a) |>
  filter(group.x == group.y, value.x < value.y)

Output:
  group.x name.x value.x group.y name.y value.y
1       1      A     0.2       1      B     0.3
2       1      A     0.2       1      C     1.0
3       1      B     0.3       1      C     1.0
4       2      A     0.3       2      B     0.6
5       2      C     0.1       2      A     0.3
6       2      C     0.1       2      B     0.6

Followed by plotting, as you've already demonstrated.
